# Where do you put downloaded filed in android

Tags: android

My application downloads files from the server and save them somewhere. Where should I put the folder to save the files? Not in assets right? Should I create a folder somewhere parallel to `"bin"`/`"libs"`/`"res"` folder?

Another question: should I put the downloaded files in internal storage or external storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can not save the downloaded file in either of this folders because they are not allowed to make modification at run time.

Best option goes according to your requirement, as if you file is too large and you are not much worried about it's security then you can store them on SDCARD(External storage). and if your file is small enough and much secure then you should save them on internal storage.

Check most popular application store their files on SDCARD but encrypted way...

Hope this ans your question

Comment: did this ans your problem? if yes then help others by accepting the ans

Answer (score 0):

Store your downloaded files in a folder on an external storage directory. like 
`String yourFolderPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + /com.yourapp/;` 
Store files in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

if its just few files, it would be safer and more convenient to use the context.getCacheDir().  with it, you can be sure that it will always be there unlike sdcard which can be locked when the phone is in storage mode. it doesnt require manifest permission. You  don't even have to worry about security unless your user is rooted.